# Why am I getting 'float' object is unsliceable

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting an error 'float' object is unsliceable
only when I use the terminal.
when I use the Pycharm it works perfectly.

basically I am trying to convert the following float
**'1.215386e+11'**
into datetime format using the following line:

```
df3["FrameTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df3["FrameTime"], format='%H%M%S%f')
```

This returns the following error with Terminal using Ubuntu 18.04 :
**'float' object is unsliceable**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: please read [mre]. This is not reproducible as you did not show `df3`.

Comment: Are you using same `env` at both the places?